# Buffered Reader/File Reader .readLine() to .split() reading but no display to console

Tags: java, filereader

I have stripped this down to the bare minimum and can't seem to work out the issue. I've done lots of inquires and have tried countless iterations. So any suggestions would be appreciated. I used a for loop to see about output from the array I hope to be getting from the input file (just a list of numbers; lines range from 1 digit to 6 digits). Ideally, the lines need to be read, out into an array, int by int. Many thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String line = "";
    int matrix[][] = new int[0][];
    String text = "line1\n\n\nline4";
    int lineNumber = 0;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("input.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((bufferedReader.readLine() != null)) {

            String stringArray[] = line.split(" ");
            for(int x = 0; x <= stringArray.length-1; x++) {
                System.out.println(stringArray[x]);
                System.out.printf("%04d: %s%n", ++lineNumber, line);
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet of the input:
  [image]

Snippet of the output:

0001: 
here

0002: 
here

0003: 
here

Comment: you're not reading the line, try replacing `while ((bufferedReader.readLine() != null))` with `while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)`

Comment: Thank you! Silly thing I missed on the millionth iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you intent to read the file as a matrix (each line a separate array of integers) this method may be helpful:

```
/**
 * Read a matrix from the specified path, each line corresponds to a 
 * separate array of integers.
 * 
 * @param path the path to the file, not null
 * @return a matrix, not null
 * @throws IOException           if an I/O error occurs opening the file
 * @throws NumberFormatException if the file contains non-parsable integers
 */
public static int[][] readMatrix(Path path) throws IOException
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(path);

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path))
    {
        return lines
                .map(String::trim) // Remove leading and trailing whitespaces.
                .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty()) // Ignore empty lines.
                .map(line -> line.split("\\s+")) // Split line by whitespaces.

                // Map tokens of type String[] to int[]
                .map(tokens -> Arrays.stream(tokens)
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // Throws NumberFormatException if not parsable
                        .toArray())
                .toArray(int[][]::new);
    } catch (UncheckedIOException e)
    {
        throw e.getCause();
    }
}
```

If you are otherwise interested in just an array of integers and don't care about splitting them by line:

```
Files.lines()
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())
    .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
    .flatMapToInt(tokens -> Arrays.stream(tokens)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt))
    .toArray();
```

Comment: I did try the readMatrix method. But when I set the path in main to call the method, I was getting a number exception error. I haven't used path in some time so I'm not sure what went wrong.              Path path1 = Paths.get("\\Lab2", "\\input.txt");
            readMatrix(path1);

Comment: @SadieRose this is related to blank lines in your input file i guess. What do you want to do when an empty line is detected? Ignore it or return an empty array for this line?

Comment: @SadieRose updated the original answer, empty lines are now ignored.